# Moving Models into a gem - Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, namespaces, rubygems, rails-engines

I have a an Engine, Called Xaaron. and a Gem called core_models. I am trying to move, as an experiment, the user model of Xaaron into the gem. Eventually I want to move all the models from the engine into the gem.

This is what I did, In the gem under `lib/core_models/models/user.rb` I did:

```
require_relative 'concerns/user_concerns'
require 'bcrypt'

module CoreModels
  module Models
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base

      extend FriendlyId
      friendly_id :first_name, use: [:slugged, :finders, :history]

      before_save :encrypt_password

      has_many :group_memberships, :dependent => :delete_all
      has_many :groups, :through => :group_memberships, :dependent => :delete_all
      has_many :roles, :through => :group_memberships, :dependent => :delete_all

      has_many :api_keys

      validates :first_name, presence: true
      validates :user_name, uniqueness: true, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
      validates :email, presence: true, confirmation: true, uniqueness: true
      validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
      validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: { minimum: 10 }, if: :new_record?

      include CoreModels::Models::Concerns::UserConcerns

      before_create{ generate_token(:auth_token) }

      def self.authenticate_user(user_name, password)
        user = Xaaron::User.find_by_user_name(user_name)
        if(user && (user.password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.salt)))
          user
        else
          nil
        end
      end

      def encrypt_password
        if password.present?
          self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
          self.password = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
        end
      end

      def send_password_reset
        generate_token(:password_reset_token)
        self.password_reset_timestamp = Time.zone.now
        save!
        UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
      end

      protected
      def generate_token(column)
        begin
          self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
        end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is the model that use to be in Xaaron.

In the Xaaron Engine, under `app/models/xaaron/user.rb` I did:

```
require 'core_models/models/user'

module Xaaron
  class User < CoreModels::Models::User
  end
end
```

As you can see I am just extending the model.

Now I assumed this would work, clearly it doesn't because anything that interacts with the user model at all is throwing, test wise:

```
 Failure/Error: create_login_admin_user
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
   LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                             ^
   :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                        pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                   FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                     ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                  WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                    AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                  ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Now Xaaron's tables are name spaced to that of `xaaron_table_names`, so in this case its `xaaron_users`

I assumed it would still know how to look at the `xaaron_users` table even though I extended another model. Clearly not.

What can I do to rectify this so that My model is still in the gem but accessible through xaaron or any other application that does or does not name space there tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not use the `xaaron_users` table because `CoreModels::Model::User` is outside of the `Xaaron` namespace, and therefore will not have the `xaaron_` prefix on your table name.

The solution is to specify the table name manually inside the model:

```
module Xaaron
  class User < CoreModels::Models::User
    self.table_name = "xaaron_users"
  end
end
```